# Get time as year/month/day/hour/minutes and convert to millisecond like getTime() in java or android

Tags: java, clock

I want to get time from user(with editbox like year/month/day/hour/minutes).
How can i convert it to millisecond like getTime function or convert to minutes like getTime()/60000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`DatePicker`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) and then use the getters from that to either make a [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object or to get the time in millis.

I use this function in my projects to get the `Calendar` from the `DatePicker`, you may want to extend it to set the hours/ minutes as well:

```
public static Calendar getCalenderFromDatePicker(DatePicker dp) {
    int day = dp.getDayOfMonth();
    int month = dp.getMonth();
    int year = dp.getYear();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(year, month, day);
    return calendar;
}
```

Once you have the `Calendar` you can use `myCalendar.getTimeInMillis()` which returns a `long` of the time in millis since the epoch.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [java.util.Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class and the following code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

int year = 2015;
int month = 4; // "May", months are counting from 0 to 11
int day = 14;
int hour = 14;
int minutes = 15;
int seconds = 16;

// for more clarity I set year/day/month/hours/minutes/seconds separately
// you can also set them at once via calendar.set(year, month, day);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, seconds);

long composedDateInMilliseconds = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```